# How to implement the default outlining tool tip in Visual Studio extension?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, vsix

I copied some code from [here](https://github.com/Skybladev2/C--outline-for-Visual-Studio) to make an extension compatible with Visual Studio 2019 to replace the built-in outlining because it does not collapse the curly braces in catch & finally block.

Now the extension works fine as the picture shows below.

[image]

But there is only one thing I'm not satisfied with. When I move the mouse to the collapsed part, it just shows plain text tooltip without any color or format.

[image]

I would like to make the tooltip look like the built-in one. But I don't know where to start.

[image]

I did some research about this. I may need to change the `hoverText` in this code.

```
return new TagSpan<IOutliningRegionTag>(span, new OutliningRegionTag(false, false, GetCollapsedText(), hoverText));
```

I think it might involve with `Classification`, `ITooltipService` or something else.

I'm new to this, could anyone give me some advice? Some demo code or document would be great help. Thanks.

Code is here: [CSharpOutline2019](https://github.com/xyz0835/CSharpOutline2019)

Answer (score 4):

After a night long research, I finally found a solution and achieved my goal.

In case anyone would be interested with this question, I'll try to exlpain how it works, giving a general idea.

- Import `IProjectionBufferFactoryService` to create the hover `TextBuffer`
- Import `ITextEditorFactoryService` to create a `IWpfTextView` to show the hover content
- Replace the parameter `hoverText` with `IWpfTextView` in the code I mentioned above

```
return new TagSpan<IOutliningRegionTag>(span, new OutliningRegionTag(false, false, GetCollapsedText(), hoverText));
```

That's pretty much it. And I found the solution [here](https://github.com/Trieste-040/https-github.com-dotnet-roslyn/blob/2d22d1aa4f1dfe3ae6f8de8cb7ddc218a5f1c4ff/src/EditorFeatures/Core/Implementation/Structure/BlockTagState.cs).

The extension works great, the tooltip looks just the same as the default one.

[image]

The complete code will be uploaded to [CSharpOutline2019](https://github.com/xyz0835/CSharpOutline2019) soon.